# Change ggplot2 point color based on date occurring less than 4 weeks after previous date

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, lubridate

I have an example dataframe composed of: 
[example dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuGXN.png)

I have used ggplot2 to plot dates on the x-axis with a count on the y-axis:

```
df_ggplot <- read.csv("ggplot_ex.csv", header = T, na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

df_ggplot$Date <- mdy(df_ggplot$Date)

df_ggplot$Ccount <- as.numeric(as.character(df_ggplot$Ccount))

ggplot(df_ggplot, aes(x=Date, y = Ccount)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[ggplot ex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mtTm.png)

I am wanting points that occur less than 4 weeks after the previous point to turn red.  Can anyone help?  In this example, the second point would be red as it occurs about 2 weeks after the previous point.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to do the calculation in the dataframe before the plot (make sure your `Date` column is in the correct `date` format).
One option you can try:

```
df_ggplot <- df_ggplot %>% 
  mutate(time_diff = difftime(time1 = Date, time2 = lag(x = Date, n = 1), units = "weeks"),
         is_red = as.factor(time_diff < 4))
```

will give you the points that must be flagged.

```
        Date Ccount      time_diff is_red
1 2019-08-17  20000       NA weeks   <NA>
2 2019-08-30  15000 1.857143 weeks   TRUE
3 2019-09-30  25000 4.285714 weeks  FALSE
```

Then you can plot, using some the colors you want.

```
ggplot(df_ggplot, aes(x = Date, y = Ccount)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(color = is_red)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"), na.value = "black")
```